# C and POSIX Pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have just started reading about threading in C, using pthreads. I know that Pthreads are available for Windows, but do multithreaded WIndows based C/C++ applications mostly use Pthreads?
Also in Unix/Linux are Pthreads the main way developers write multithreaded C/C++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, most will use the thread abstraction of the application/gui library they are using, e.g. MFC. Or in the plain C case, using the windows API directly.

Pthreads stands for "POSIX" threads, which is basically standarized unix(-like), a standard that  has little meaning on Windows outside dedicated POSIX emulations like cygwin.

Comment: So if I'm mainly interested in Windows programming Pthreads aren't all that useful?

Comment: Pthreads are not-stanard to windows programming, but there is an implementation of pthreads for windows (if you want to do portable thread programming)

Comment: pthreads dont really have any big disadvantages compared to using the WINAPI directly, but you have the big advantage, that the pthreads code would work on other OSs aswell, if you want to make your application cross-platform later on.

Comment: smerlin: If so, what is the equivalent for WaitforMultiplehandles? :-) And what pthreads lib would you use that doesn't come with some non native windows emulation lib attached?

Answer (score 0):

The new C++ Standard, C++11, has support for portable threads. I'd definitely go with that, except that Visual Studio hasn't implemented them yet.